# the diffrence between persistent cookies and temporary cookies

Tags: php, cookies

this is a question that I didn't understood why option B isn't correct also:

Q: Which of the following statements are true about cookies 
A.You cannot delete a persistent or temporary cookie.
B.Persistent cookies can be used for tracking long-term information.
C.Temporary cookies are safer than persistent cookies because no programs other than the browser can access them. 
D.When the browser is closed, temporary cookies will be erased.
correct answers are: C,D

Answer (score 0):

Found on Google :

http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html

> Persistent cookies – these files stay in one of your browser's subfolders until you delete them manually or your browser deletes them based on the duration period contained within the persistent cookie's file
>
> Session cookies - these are temporary cookie files, which are erased when you close your browser. When you restart your browser and go back to the site that created the cookie, the website will not recognize you.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, B is also a correct option. What was this, an exam question or something? Then the person who set the question is wrong. If it's important, you have grounds to appeal!

In fact the whole point of persistent cookies is to hold information long term, by which I mean from one visit to another, even if the PC has been powered down meanwhile. They can last indefinitely if specified to do so. In that case the information will only be deleted if you do so via the browser's set up options.

So, for instance, a site that can display in several languages will ask you which language you want, and hold that in a persistent cookie, so they never have to ask you again.

Comment: thanks, it just a question from an exam of a site, that I am preparing with to a test.